# Encounter issue installing of Sitecore XP0. The declared parameter 'Search SOLR Core Application Connection String' is not recognized

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore9

I installed Sitecore 9.0.2 XP Single Topology PAAS. Unfortunately, the installation is not successful because it looks like the ConnectionString I specified is not valid.

```
 {
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "Conflict",
      "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.\",\r\n        \"details\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n            \"message\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"status\\\": \\\"Failed\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n    \\\"code\\\": \\\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"details\\\": [\\r\\n      {\\r\\n        \\\"code\\\": \\\"DeploymentFailed\\\",\\r\\n        \\\"message\\\": \\\"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.\\\",\\r\\n        \\\"details\\\": [\\r\\n          {\\r\\n            \\\"code\\\": \\\"Conflict\\\",\\r\\n            \\\"message\\\": \\\"{\\\\r\\\\n  \\\\\\\"status\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"failed\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n  \\\\\\\"error\\\\\\\": {\\\\r\\\\n    \\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n    \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n    \\\\\\\"details\\\\\\\": [\\\\r\\\\n      {\\\\r\\\\n        \\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Failed\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n        \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: The declared parameter 'Search SOLR Core Application Connection String' is not recognized.\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.LoadFromFile(XPathNavigator nav, String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.LoadSetParameters(DeploymentObject deploymentObject, IDictionary`2 setParams, String setParamXmlFile)\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete)\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__17.MoveNext()'\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\\n      }\\\\r\\\\n    ]\\\\r\\\\n  }\\\\r\\\\n}\\\"\\r\\n          }\\r\\n        ]\\r\\n      }\\r\\n    ]\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the parameter I specified in the template:

```
},
    "solrConnectionString": {
      "value": "http://avanade-smart-solr-paas.azurewebsites.net/solr"
    },
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For Sitecore it is required that SOLR runs on https,
so you need first fix a ssl certificate and supply a working https url.

Are you running SOLR on app services?, a experimental environment. but with a built-in SSL certificate. See this blog for how to install this https://getfishtank.ca/blog/installing-solr-app-service-in-sitecore-azure-paas